# Issues in turning a perl chat program to a web page

Tags: javascript, html, perl, chat

I have the below server and client codes in perl for chatting.

## server code

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::Select;

$| = 1;
my $serv = IO::Socket::INET->new(
LocalAddr => '0.0.0.0',
LocalPort => '5000',
Reuse => 1,
Listen => 1,
);

$serv or die "$!";

print 'server up...';
my $sel = IO::Select->new($serv); #initializing IO::Select with an IO::Handle / Socket

print "\nAwaiting Connections\n";


while(1){
if(my @ready = $sel->can_read(0)){ #polls the IO::Select object for IO::Handles /     Sockets that can be read from
    while(my $sock = shift(@ready)){
        if($sock == $serv){
            my $client = $sock->accept();
            my $paddr = $client->peeraddr();
            my $pport = $client->peerport();

            print "New connection from $paddr on $pport";

            $sel->add($client);
                        #for read/writability with can_read and can_write
        }
        else{
            $sock->recv(my $data, 1024) or die "$!";
            if($data){                  
                for my $clients ($sel->can_write(0)){
                    if($clients == $serv){next}
                    print $clients $data;
                }

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

#client code#

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
use CGI;
my $q = new CGI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use threads;
use IO::Select;

$| = 1;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new("localhost:5000");
$sock or die "$!";
my $sel = IO::Select->new($sock);

print $q->header;
my $line = $q->param("login");
print $line;
print " <META http-equiv=\"refresh\" > ";
print "Connected to Socket ". $sock->peeraddr().":" . $sock->peerport() . "\n";
# content="URL=ipl7.pl"
#This creates a thread that will be used to take info from STDIN and send it out
#through the socket.

threads->create(
sub {
 #   while(1){
        chomp($line);
        for my $out (my @ready = $sel->can_write(0)){
            print $out $line;
   #     }
    }   
  }
);

# while(1){
if(my @ready = $sel->can_read(0)){
    for my $sock(@ready){
        $sock->recv(my $data, 1024) or die $!;
        print "$data","\n" if $data;
#        }
  }

}
```

## chat web page

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" />

<input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" onclick="verifyLoginRequest();return  true;" />

<div id="id_id">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
//        if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('login').click();
document.getElementById('txtSearch').value="";
}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function createRequestObject() {
  var req;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Firefox, Safari, Opera...
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Internet Explorer 5+
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
// error creating the request object,
// (maybe an old browser is being used?)
alert('There was a problem creating the XMLHttpRequest object');
req = '';
}
return req;
}

// Make the XMLHttpRequest object
var http_login = createRequestObject();

function verifyLoginRequest() {
var login = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
if ( login ) {
var url = 'dd.pl?login='+login;
  http_login.open('get', url );
 http_login.onreadystatechange = handleLoginResponse;
 http_login.send(null);
 }
}

function handleLoginResponse() {
 if(http_login.readyState == 4 && http_login.status == 200){
 var response = http_login.responseText; // Text returned FROM perl script
 if(response) { // UPDATE ajaxTest content
 document.getElementById("id_id").innerHTML = response;  

   }
  }
}

</script>
```

the following error is displayed
 Perl exited with active threads:
 \t1 running and unjoined
 \t0 finished and unjoined,
 \t0 running and detached

What is this error about and how to clear this error?

Comment: Hi, i suggest using a webframework and websockets to write a chat application. So you don't need to write all the socket handling by yourself. An example can be found here: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite

Comment: +1 to @jfried, as I could not agree more, and I use `MOJO` for this now in a few projects (first one was based on that exact git repo).